# Where multicast packets could be filtered?

Tags: multicast, avahi, ebtables

I installed openWRT distro on my router and enable support of avahi in it. My goal is to discover network services in my network.

I plugged my PC to LAN port with announced services. On router I run tcpdump on bridge interface : `tcpdump -i br0 -vvn udp port 5353`

During avahi browse execution i receive output:
root@localhost:~# avahi-browse -art

```
21:55:22.995004 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 74)
    192.168.1.1.5353 > 224.0.0.251.5353: [udp sum ok] 0 PTR (QM)? _services._dns-sd._udp.local. (46)
```

But on my PC wireshark didn't show any multicast queries during that call, hence no services found.

Does it mean that router filter multicast packets somehow? 
Only way that i know is to filter in ebtables, which shows nothing about filtering of mDNS addresses:

```
root@localhost:~# ebtables -L
Bridge table: filter

Bridge chain: INPUT, entries: 1, policy: ACCEPT
-j RO_INPUT

Bridge chain: FORWARD, entries: 1, policy: ACCEPT
-j RO

Bridge chain: OUTPUT, entries: 1, policy: ACCEPT
-j IGMPPROXY

Bridge chain: RO, entries: 0, policy: RETURN

Bridge chain: RO_INPUT, entries: 0, policy: RETURN

Bridge chain: IGMPPROXY, entries: 4, policy: RETURN
-p IPv4 -o wl0.1 --ip-dst 239.0.0.0/8 -j DROP 
-p IPv4 -o wl0.2 --ip-dst 239.0.0.0/8 -j DROP 
-p IPv4 -o wl0.3 --ip-dst 239.0.0.0/8 -j DROP 
-p IPv4 -o br0 --ip-dst 239.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
```

Where these multicast packets could be filtered/dropped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that in my router snooping was enabled, which i think corresponds to [IGMP snooping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IGMP_snooping)

After disabling it, multicast DNS queries reached destination and were show be wireshark.

Here what i've done (of course path could vary in different hardware and distro):

```
echo "0" > /proc/hwswitch/default/snooping
```